# Feedburner awareness API 0 circulation

Tags: google-api, feedburner

The feedburner awareness API seemed to be working fine till last night but its not working right now. Its not even down but returning 0 for every site. I wonder if there is something I am missing or have the removed this functionality or something.

https://feedburner.google.com/api/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri=http://feeds.feedburner.com/RandomGoodStuff

However if I give dates with feedburner it gives the values.

https://feedburner.google.com/api/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri=http://feeds2.feedburner.com/RandomGoodStuff&dates=2008-01-01,2008-04-02

Anyone knows what is going on? I tried looking for any change in the API but didn't find any. Neither could I find a way to ask google about it.

Comment: Getting the same exact problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I still see it, and still using the same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Awareness API documentation, **circulation** — an approximate measure of the number of individuals for whom your feed has been **requested in the 24 hour period** described by date. So just add `&dates=YYYY-MM-DD`, where date is a day before yesterday. This way you will always get the result, fresh and grater than zero.

Comment: Without dates parameter it ueses a today date, but at the beginning of the day the feed has not been requested yet, so the number is 0.